# How to distribute routes by day of the month?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I need help with the distribution of routes by day of the month.

The situation is as follows. There are, for example, **3 zones**, each zone has routes (not always the same number).
The task is to distribute routes by weekdays in a month, but there is a condition: routes from two **NOT** zones can be assigned for one day, **zones must not overlap**.

**Example:**

**Routes of 1 zone:** *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 , 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43; *

**Routes 2 zones:** *44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 , 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79;*

**Routes 3 zones:** *80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100 , 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120;*

It turns out 120 routes (for example) per month. Let's say there are 20 days in a month, respectively, we divide 120 by 20, we get 6 routes per day.
As a result, we should get the distribution of routes by working days of the week in the following form:
1-6,7-12,13-18,19-24,25-30,31-36,37-43,44-49,50-55,56-61,62-67,68-73,74-79,80-85,86-91,92-97,98-103,104-109,110-115,116-120

As is clear from the number of "number-number" blocks (from which route by which), this is distributed over 20 days.
You can also see that the routes do not intersect zones, i.e. in 1 day there is no such thing:
"43-49", because route 43 is from the 1st zone, and the rest from the 2nd.

As a result, I began to write an algorithm to distribute everything and I could not think of anything better (so far) how to create a two-dimensional array, i.e. an array in which there are arrays with zones, these arrays have route numbers.
Then I wrote a function that distributes these routes without mixing them between zones by recursion and creating a **THREE-DIMENSIONAL** array.

Then I print the first and last element of each array and get, for example, a string:
*'1-6,7-12,13-18,19-24,25-30,31-36,37-43,44-49,50-55,56-61,62-67,68-73,74-79,80-85,86-91,92-97,98-103,104-109,110-115,116-120'*;

**P.S.** I had to fix it a little, because it was the case that depending on the number of working days in a week, there could be 1 routes per day, which is bad, so I added a feature that iterates over an array of arrays and if the length of the nested is less than or equal to three (the number of routes is less than or equal to 3m), then we put it in the previous day (as it were)

**In theory, everything works, but there is a huge BUT.** It does not always work adequately due to the different number of working days in a month. **For example:** In a month there are 22 working days, and the algorithm divides everything in total into 19 blocks, which corresponds to 19 days, or if 17 working days, then divides into 21 blocks, which is equal to 21 days (BUT THIS IS ONLY AN EXAMPLE, real the numbers can be seen when testing my code).

Can you please tell me how I can correct the code so that the number of allocated blocks is strictly equal to the number of working days (does not depend on the number of working days)?

```js
// Array a - routs
const a = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43],
[44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
[80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120]
];
const days = 20;
const countRoutsInDay = Math.floor(a.flat().length / days);
const newArr = [];
const resultArr = [];
let str = '';

// Divide into arrays by day
const splitterRouts = (count) => {
  let arr = [];
  let currentElemOfMainArray = count;
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(a[count].length / countRoutsInDay); i++) {
    arr[i] = a[count].slice((i * countRoutsInDay), (i * countRoutsInDay) + countRoutsInDay);

    if (i === Math.ceil(a[count].length / countRoutsInDay) - 1) {
      currentElemOfMainArray += 1;
      newArr.push(arr);
      if (currentElemOfMainArray < a.length) {
        splitterRouts(currentElemOfMainArray);
      }
    }
  }
}

splitterRouts(0);

// If there are less than or equal to 3 routes, then connect on the previous day
newArr.forEach((el) => {
  el.forEach((el2) => {
    if (el2.length <= 3) {
      const summRoute = el[el.length - 2].concat(el[el.length - 1]);
      el.splice(el.indexOf(el[el.length - 2]), el.indexOf(el[el.length - 1]), summRoute);
    }
  })
});

newArr.forEach((el) => {
  el.forEach((el2) => {
    str += `${el2[0]}-${el2[el2.length - 1]},`
    resultArr.push(str.split(','));
  })
})

console.log(str);
console.log(resultArr.length - 1); // this result must be equal to the number of days given above
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends a bit on one decision: what should happen to zone 3 (41 routs) if there are 22 days? Should it be split into 6 days of 5 routs and one day of 11 routs? Or should the routs be evenly distributed with six days of 7 routs and one day of 6 routs? If it's the former, then you'll need to change the bit of code regarding "less than or equal to 3" to append any excess routs to the last day for that zone. Assuming you want the days more distributed more evenly, this solution accomplishes the second case:

First, days are distributed across all the zones (with the biggest zones getting any remainder). Next, within each zone, routs are distributed across days (with the later days getting more routs):

```
// Array a - routs
const a = [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43],
[44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
[80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120]
];
const days =20;

//evenly distributing the days among the zones, leaving any remaining days on the longest zone(s)
 const countRoutsInDay2 = a.map((aInnerArr,i)=>[aInnerArr.length,i]).sort()/*.map(a=>a[1])*/.reverse();
 const countRoutsInDay3 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      countRoutsInDay3[i] = Math.floor(days/a.length);
      if (i >= (a.length - (days % (Math.floor(days/a.length))) )) {countRoutsInDay3[i]++};
    } 
countRoutsInDay3.reverse();
let countDaysForZone = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   countDaysForZone[countRoutsInDay2[i][1]] = countRoutsInDay3[i];
 }
const newArr = [];
const resultArr = [];
let str = '';
let countRoutsInDay = 5;
// similarly, dividing each zone into days as evenly as possible, with the longer days later
const splitterRouts = (count) => {
  let arr = [];
  let currentElemOfMainArray = count;
  let routsOnThisDay = [];
  let daysForThisArray = countDaysForZone[count];
  for (let i = 0; i < daysForThisArray; i++){
    routsOnThisDay[i] = Math.floor(a[count].length/daysForThisArray);
    if (i >= (daysForThisArray - (a[count].length % daysForThisArray) )) {routsOnThisDay[i]++};
  } 
  
  for (let i = 0; i < countDaysForZone[count]; i++) {
    let routsSoFar = 0;
    if (i==1){routsSoFar = routsOnThisDay[0];}
    if (i>1){
       routsSoFar = routsOnThisDay.slice(0,i).reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
    }
  arr[i] = a[count].slice(routsSoFar, routsSoFar + routsOnThisDay[i]);
  
    if (i === countDaysForZone[count] - 1) {
      currentElemOfMainArray += 1;
      newArr.push(arr);
      if (currentElemOfMainArray < a.length) {
        splitterRouts(currentElemOfMainArray);
      }
    }
  }
}

splitterRouts(0);

// If there are less than or equal to 3 routes, then connect on the previous day
newArr.forEach((el) => {
  el.forEach((el2) => {
    if (el2.length <= 3) {
      const summRoute = el[el.length - 2].concat(el[el.length - 1]);
      el.splice(el.indexOf(el[el.length - 2]), el.indexOf(el[el.length - 1]), summRoute);
    }
  })
});

newArr.forEach((el) => {
  el.forEach((el2) => {
    str += `${el2[0]}-${el2[el2.length - 1]},`
    resultArr.push(str.split(','));
  })
})

console.log(str);
console.log(resultArr.length - 1);
```